# Version lie shim for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014 is sufficiently new that not a lot of the 3rd party tooling has caught up with it yet. I'm looking at Red Gate and TOAD in particular...

[image: Error message from SQL Doc 3]

Is there any way of putting a version lie shim in place on the server until these tools have released newer versions?

**EDIT: 2014-05-29 16:00 IST**

In response to the hold I'd like to emphasise that this question is about getting the *server* to lie about its version so that *all* tools will which have worked to date should continue to work.

Even though two particular vendors have been mentioned this is just by way of example and it should be stated that I'm not looking for a fix for the particular issue shown in the screenshot - that's just there to illustrate my point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 3rd-party product at a specific moment in time. Please contact the vendor and encourage them to add support for the new version of SQL Server.

Comment: Edited to answer charges. Please review...

Comment: Redgate SQL Compare plainly crashed on SQL14 instances 6 month after the SQL Server release. They don't take this seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  You'll have to hold off on Monitoring with the 3rd party tools until they release new builds which support the new versions.  The good news is that they are all smallish companies so they can release new builds pretty quickly.  I'd recommend contacting their support departments and see if there's a new build available, maybe even a BETA that you can try out.

I feel you're pain, I've got a client with SQL 2014 in production and Spotlight can't monitor it for them.